# How to use while(1) loop in arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have been trying to exit from the `while(1)` loop by getting a value from the sensor and then run the code outside `while(1)`.But the problem is that it does not exit. How may I fix this problem?

See Code Below.......

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(2,INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    int sensor;
    while(1)
    {
        sensor = digitalRead(2);
        if(sensor == 0)
        {
            Serial.println("inside while loop");
        }
        break;
    }
    Serial.println("Break......");
}
```

Comment: The `while(1)` loop executes once, every time `loop()` is called, printing or not, depending on the state of pin2. I would expect this code to print: either "inside while loop" (if pin 2 is false) or nothing, followed by "Break......"; over and over again. Is that what you're getting? Your question is incomplete. Please describe what you expected to see, and what you do see, on the terminal.

Comment: The `loop` function loops (is called repeatedly). Why do you put an indefinite loop inside a function that is called indefinitely?

Answer (score 6):

In the Arduino paradigm, unlike ordinary C programming where there is only 1 entry point called "main()", there are 2 entry points called "setup()" and "loop()".  "setup()" is called only once after booting up.  But "loop()" is called over and over again right after "setup()" is called.  There is no need to create your own infinite loop (for example a "while(1)" statement) as in ordinary C programming.

Comment: Is there anyway to come out of while(1) loop inside void loop()

Comment: Sorry for the delay, holidays.  Yes, but most do not think this is good programming.  You can execute a 'break" inside the loop and exit the loop.   [This Stackexchange question / answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485340/how-to-exit-while1-loop-after-sometime-in-c) goes into the details.

Answer (score 1):

instead of while(1), one can use the variable name in while and change the value of the variable when you want to exit the loop. part of the code can be modified based on the following concept. 
`bool condition= true; 
while(condition){ 
if (sensor==0)
condition=false;`
This is my suggestion for the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

Used like this

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(2,INPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
     bool cond = true;

int sensor;
while(cond)
{
    sensor = digitalRead(2);
    if(sensor == 0)
    {
        Serial.println("inside while loop");
    }
    cond = false;
}

  // like this you can used while inside the void loop()

}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explaination on how this solves the problem.